# Query with multiple fields and conditions in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch is possible transform this SQL in one query?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE state IN ('NY', 'CA', 'FL') AND grade IN ('GOOD', 'BAD') AND active = 'YES' AND quantity > 100 AND quantity < 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a **[`filtered` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html)** with a **[`bool` filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html#query-dsl-bool-filter)** for this

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
      },
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [{
              "terms" : {
                "state" : [
                  "NY",
                  "CA",
                  "FL"
                ]
              }
            }, 
            {
              "terms" : {
                "grade" : [
                  "GOOD",
                  "BAD"
                ]
              }
            }, 
            {
              "term" : {
                "active" : "YES"
              }
            }, 
            {
              "range" : {
                "quantity" : {
                  "gt" : 100,
                  "lt" : 200
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And if quantity is just `quantity > 100`?

Comment: just remove the `lt` property on the range filter i.e. `{ "range" : { "quantity" :{  "gt" : 100 } } }`