# Elasticsearch query Based on multiple conditions

Tags: elasticsearch, conditional-statements

I am trying to search based on multiple parameters.
For example, my doc structure is following,

```
{
"id": "101",
"start_time": "2021-12-13T06:57:29.420198Z",
"end_time": "2021-12-13T07:00:23.511722Z",
"data": [{
        "starttimestamp": "2022-01-03T11:21:22.107413Z",
        "user": "John",
        "speech": "Thanks. I’m just happy that it’s over. I was really nervous about it.",
        "endtimestamp": "2022-01-03T11:21:22.247482Z"
    },
    {
        "starttimestamp": "2022-01-03T11:21:26.905401Z",
        "user": "Tom",
        "speech": "Well, I’m sure you did great. where is the university",
        "endtimestamp": "2022-01-03T11:21:27.065316Z"
    },
    {
        "starttimestamp": "2022-01-03T11:21:33.165617Z",
        "user": "John",
        "speech": "university is in canada.",
        "endtimestamp": "2022-01-03T11:21:33.165900Z"
    }
]
```

}

Now I need to search for a particular user,

Ex:
Positive case: search for the doc where user is "John" who spoke about "canada" at starttimestamp "2022-01-03T11:21:33.165617Z"
output : we should get result for above query

Negative case: search for a doc where user "Tom" who spoke about "canada" at starttimestamp "2022-01-03T11:21:33.165617Z"
output : the result should be empty here, as "Tom" did not talk about "canada"

I tried to achieve expected o/p using following queries,

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "term": {"data.user": "Tom"}
            },
            {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {"term": {"data.speech": "canada"}}
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

in the above query, we should be getting an empty list but we are getting the above doc as result.

I have referred some other resources:
[Conditional based Elastic Search Query (if else or Union case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68075013/conditional-based-elastic-search-query-if-else-or-union-case)
[Query with multiple fields and conditions in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665399/query-with-multiple-fields-and-conditions-in-elasticsearch)

I didn't find the exact info which can fix my issue.

Comment: can you please post your index mapping as well ?

Comment: Please check below my answer and marked as solution if it really helps you

Comment: @SagarPatel Thank you so much, it's working as expected. thanks again for saving my time.

Comment: its my pleasure.

Comment: @SagarPatel Hey, do you have any info on my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71409311/elasticsearch-search-by-time-range ? 
I am not able to find any solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) for how array field work in Elasticsearch. As you are using array of object, you can not query each object individual.

> Arrays of objects do not work as you would expect: you cannot query
> each object independently of the other objects in the array. If you
> need to be able to do this then you should use the **nested** data type
> instead of the object data type.

You can **create index** using below sample:

```json
PUT index_name
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "data":{
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index below document**:

```json
POST index_name/_doc
{
  "id": "101",
  "start_time": "2021-12-13T06:57:29.420198Z",
  "end_time": "2021-12-13T07:00:23.511722Z",
  "data": [
    {
      "starttimestamp": "2022-01-03T11:21:22.107413Z",
      "user": "John",
      "speech": "Thanks. I’m just happy that it’s over. I was really nervous about it.",
      "endtimestamp": "2022-01-03T11:21:22.247482Z"
    },
    {
      "starttimestamp": "2022-01-03T11:21:26.905401Z",
      "user": "Tom",
      "speech": "Well, I’m sure you did great. where is the university",
      "endtimestamp": "2022-01-03T11:21:27.065316Z"
    },
    {
      "starttimestamp": "2022-01-03T11:21:33.165617Z",
      "user": "John",
      "speech": "university is in canada.",
      "endtimestamp": "2022-01-03T11:21:33.165900Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Sample Query:**

```json
POST index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "data",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "data.user": "John"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "data.speech": "canada"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please check [this](https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/data-structuring/elasticsearch-nested-field-object-field/) blog for more clear understanding of object and nested type.